# How to know the shape of the .ppm file on CentOS

Tags: linux, image, file

I wonder if there is any command or tool that can show the size of the image(like .ppm), namely, height, width, and the number of channels. Now I have to do this by writing some scripts using PIL, a package of python. But it's not so convenient. Is there a more elegant way?

Thank you very much for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **exiftool** or **ImageMagick**, where the latter is a significantly bigger installation.

With **exiftool**:

```
exiftool -p '${filename}:${ImageWidth}:${ImageHeight}' -q -f *ppm
```

**Sample Output**

```
P3.ppm:100:100
P6.ppm:100:100
extracted-000.ppm:544:149
extracted-001.ppm:185:116
extracted-002.ppm:185:116
extracted-003.ppm:265:609
result.ppm:64:64
savedP3.ppm:64:64
savedP6.ppm:64:64
```

I realise this doesn't show number of channels, but maybe it is sufficient to add `${MIMEType}` to the end of the list and you'll get `image/x-portable-graymap` or `image/x-portable-pixmap` which may be good enough for your needs.

---

With **ImageMagick** which is included in most Linux distros and is available for macOS and Windows. Just in Terminal:

```
magick identify -format "%f:%w:%h:%[colorspace]\n" *ppm *pgm
```

**Sample Output**

```
P3.ppm:100:100:sRGB
P6.ppm:100:100:sRGB
extracted-000.ppm:544:149:sRGB
extracted-001.ppm:185:116:sRGB
extracted-002.ppm:185:116:sRGB
extracted-003.ppm:265:609:sRGB
result.ppm:64:64:sRGB
savedP3.ppm:64:64:sRGB
savedP6.ppm:64:64:sRGB
a.pgm:33:16:Gray
```

You can also include the bit-depth, x-resolution, y-resolution, number of colours and so on by checking the available [Escapes](https://imagemagick.org/script/escape.php).

It will work for JPEG, PNG, TIFF, TGA, GIF and 260 other formats too. If still using the old v6 version, the command becomes:

```
identify -format "%f:%w:%h:%[colorspace]\n" *ppm *pgm
```